# Xamarin - Refresh listview after Post

Tags: c#, rest, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a **Xamarin Forms App**, it has a tabbed page.  One of the tabs contains a `ListView` control showing data consumed from a Rest API.  If I tap the add button a modal shows where I can create new items and send post to the Rest API.  After success I pop the modal from navigation what leaves the `ListView` showing.  In my `ListView`, the last added item is not showing.

How can I manage to refresh the `ListView` calling the Rest API after I add an item?

Here is my XAML page: *BonosView.xaml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns ="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:iconize="clr-namespace:FormsPlugin.Iconize;assembly=FormsPlugin.Iconize"
    x:Class="rodriguez.BonosView" x:Name="BonosView"
    Title="Bonos">

    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0, 20, 0, 0" />
    </ContentPage.Padding>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="BonosListMessage" IsVisible="false" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="No exixten bonos para mostrar"/>
            <ListView x:Name="BonosList" ItemTapped="ViewDetails" RowHeight="70" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.Padding>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="10,5" Android="10,5"/>
                                </Grid.Padding>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label x:Name="monto" Text="{Binding Monto}" Style="{DynamicResource TitleListBono}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                <Label x:Name="nombre" Text="{Binding nombreCompleto}" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                <Label x:Name="estado" Text="{Binding Estado}" FontSize="Small" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" TextColor="Green"/>
                                <Label x:Name="montoRD" Text="{Binding MontoRD}" FontSize="Small" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                <Label x:Name="fecha" Text="{Binding fechaCompra, StringFormat='{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}'}" FontSize="Small" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                  </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
              </ListView>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And here is the method I call to populate the list:

```
async void refreshData()
{
    this.IsBusy = true;
    bonosLista = await manager.GetAll();  //obtaining bonos from Server

    if (bonosLista != null)
    {
        if (bonosLista.Count() > 0)
        {
            BonosList.ItemsSource = bonosLista;
        }
        else
        {
            BonosList.IsVisible = false;
            BonosListMessage.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error!", "Se ha producido un error en la conexión", "OK");
    }

    this.IsBusy = false;
}
```

I would like to call that method after the modal pops.

Comment: I would use MessagingCenter to send a message after the Post completes, that would then tell the LIstView to refresh it's data

Comment: if you define binding for BonosList.ItemsSource in your model as ObservableCollectionthe bonosLista then list should update

Comment: it does if I push to the list @YuriS

Comment: what do you mean by "push"? This line should do it: BonosList.ItemsSource = bonosLista;

Comment: push = add the object to the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Appearing` event is correct but you also need to not use `async void` on a method unless it is an event handler

Update `refreshData` method to use `async Task`

```
async Task refreshData() {
    this.IsBusy = true;
    bonosLista = await manager.GetAll();  //obtaining bonos from Server

    if (bonosLista != null) {
        if (bonosLista.Count() > 0) {
            BonosList.ItemsSource = bonosLista;
        } else {
            BonosList.IsVisible = false;
            BonosListMessage.IsVisible = true;
        }
    } else {
        await DisplayAlert("Error!", "Se ha producido un error en la conexión", "OK");
    }
    this.IsBusy = false;
}
```

Event handlers are the only places where async void can be used so update to

```
this.Appearing += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    await refreshData();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using `Appearing` method on the page containing the listview so when the modal pops I can refresh inside that method.  Maybe is not the best solution buy it's working right now.

```
this.Appearing += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
            refreshData();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the built-in [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) for this instead such that you don't have to refresh the entire list. In the command for the Add button use MessagingCenter to Send the new "bonos" item and in the page/viewmodel where the list is already rendered subscribe to that message to add it to the item collection already in existence.